# Dimensional analysis of Torque, Angular Acceleration and Mass

Tags: mechanical-engineering

It's been a long day and I'm tired, I am hoping one of you kind people can help me out.
I have been doing some simple angular momentum and torque calcs, but for the life of me I cannot resolve the units in my head.

So we know that
$$\tau=I\alpha\;\;\;\;\;or\;\;\;\;\;\tau=mr^2\alpha$$
Breaking this down for dimensional analysis:
$$Nm=kg.m^2.rad/s/s$$
However if one decides to use the Moment of Inertia in kg.mm^2, one cannot accurately convert the torque later as
$$Nm\ne Nmm/1000$$
As I get an answer out by 3 orders of magnitude!

I realise it is the square that is causing the issue as it is the equivalent the linear equation F=ma, but with a radius added for torque and the square is to describe the mass distribution. But what happens to the extra "m" or "mm" unit from the square? and why aren't the Nm and Nmm values equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Newton is not a basic unit. We only have five basic units, which are  Length (m), Mass (Kg), Time (s), Temperature (K), and Current (A). If you resolve the N to its basic units, you would come up with $$ \frac{Kg.m}{s^2} $$(coming from the F=ma relation).  Now by using these units for N, it would satisfy the overall units on both right and left side of the equation: τ=Iα.

Now, no matter whether you want to use m or mm, the units on right hand side will always equate to left hand side.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly is that you are trying to convert $I\cdot \alpha$.

The units of $I$ are either $kg\cdot (mm)^2$ or in SI $kg\cdot (m)^2$.

Since $\alpha = \frac{rad}{s^2}$, combinding both yields:

$$I\cdot \alpha  = kg\cdot (mm)^2 \cdot \frac{rad}{s^2} = kg\cdot (10^{-3}m)^2 \cdot \frac{rad}{s^2} $$

$$I\cdot \alpha  = 10^{-6}\cdot kg\cdot m^2 \cdot \frac{rad}{s^2} $$

Answer (score 1):

So there's nothing like a long drive home to clarify a couple of things. To try and work out where I was going wrong I tried to equate F = ma to Fr = rma as a torque, however I forgot that acceleration in the linear formula is m/s so the dimensional analysis of this would be:

$$Nmm = mm.kg.m/s^2$$ or as Rameez & NMech point out: $$Nmm.10^{-3} = (mm^2.kg)/s^2$$
So as the 2nd "r" in the rotational formula is for the acceleration measured in rad/s, a dimensionless unit. So if I wanted to use $$kg.mm^2$$for the moment of inertia, I would have to use the units $$mNmm$$ or milli-Newton millimeters for the torque. Hope that makes sense, happy to receive any comments.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use consistent units but watch out for conversion for the force ($F = mg$, unit $N = kg*m/s^2$)

**- Using $m$ as base unit:**

$T = F*d, unit = \dfrac {kg*m}{s^2}*m* = \dfrac{kg*m}{s^2}*m$

$T = I*\alpha = m*r^2\alpha, unit = kg*m*m*\dfrac{rad}{s^2} = \dfrac{kg*m}{s^2}*m$

**- Using $mm$ as base unit:**

$T = F*d, unit = \dfrac {kg*mm}{s^2}*mm*\dfrac{m}{1000mm} = \dfrac{kg*m}{s^2}*\dfrac{mm}{1000}$

$T = I*\alpha = m*r^2\alpha, unit = kg*mm*mm*\dfrac{rad}{s^2}*\dfrac{m}{1000mm} = \dfrac{kg*m}{s^2}*\dfrac{mm}{1000}$